# Displaying View via .sheet() causes AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute

Tags: macos, swiftui

If i display the same custom view in ContentView everthing is fine, but displaying in a modal .sheet() view causes attributeGraph cycle errors. If i comment out the call in the ContentView, the problem remains. This does not affect apps behaviour, so far. I suggest that the LazyVGrid makes in modal situations via .sheet() trouble. Is there any work around?

xcode version 13.4.1 and macOS (12.4) target

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var dialogSimple = false
    
    var buttons: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("simple") {
                dialogSimple = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $dialogSimple) {
                DialogSimple() // with Graph cycle error !
            }
        }
        .padding(.all)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DataView() // without Graph cycle error !
            buttons
            Text("Test Dialog via .sheet() shows error:")
            Text("AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute ...")
        }
        .padding(.all)
        .font(.headline)
        
    }

}

struct DialogSimple: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DataView()
            Button("Close") {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
            .padding(.all)
        }
    }

}

struct DataView: View {
    
    var columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: 2)

    var body: some View {
         LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
             Text("Field 1")
             Text("Value1")
             Text("Field 2")
             Text("Value2")
         }.frame(width: 300.0).font(.body)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Works fine. Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: Sorry: the target info is: xcode Version 13.4.1 and MacOS Target

Comment: Works fine with macOS 12.4

Comment: I have macOS 12.4

Comment: If it is only logs and does not affect app behavior then ignore them - sh..t happens :)

Comment: As you've noticed it is related to "lazyness" of the view. One hypothesis could be that there are two lazy views depending on the same data for their layout, so changing one should change the other, resulting in a circular dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but if i comment out the call in the ContentView, the problem remains.